# What would be a good way of storing geo data and calculating no. of polygon/point intersections?

Tags: .net, sql-server, geo

I have a set of rows (approx. 500K) which consists of addresses with the following geo data:

- Location (x, y)
- A pologyon (a set of coordinates)

The polygon is user defined and individual for each address.

I have the following use cases:

1. For each address I want to keep an up-to-date counter identifying how many other addresses is present within the polygon of this address.
2. For each address I want to keep an up-to-date counter identifying how many of the other addresses have this specific address within their polygon.

In a simplied relational model it looks something like this.

- AddressId (uniqueidentifier)
- Address  (string)
- LocationX (double)
- LocationY (double)
- Polygon
- NoOfAddressesInsideMyPolygon (int)
- NoOfPolygonsImContainedWithin (int)

In the relational world of SQL Server the combined LocationX + LocationY could be a spatial geography data type, and the same for storing the polygon.

I did a prototype of this in SQL Server using the spatial features. Using STIntersects I can basically:

- count the no. of records where the full set of locations which intersects with a specific polygon (NoOfAddressesInsideMyPolygon)
- count the no. of records where the full set of polygons intersects with a specific location/coordinate

I might be missing the correct spatial indexing, but doing a full calculation of the above for all of the 500K rows is rather slow.

I can somewhat live with the intial pain of calculating this, but keeping the data current whenever a new address is added to the set needs another approach.
I can easily be calculated for the single address added, but figuring out which of the other records I need to recalculate got me stuck.

So perhaps the relational model is not what is best suited for this. 
I did think about bending the requirement to try to avoid keeping updated counter for the full set at all times. 
Instead perhaps be able to quickly calculate the counters for a specific address on-the-fly when needed. But that would require it to be a lot faster that what I'm currently seeing on SQL Server.

Another thought, which I'm not sure of how to go about, would be to restrict the area for which the calculations needs to be made. One idea would be to always only do the calculations within addresses in the same postal code, or within some fixed max distance.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: To tag onto @JuanCarlosOropeza's comment, what query did you use to obtain your result set. That, along with the T-SQL table definition would help a lot I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly.

But if you have 500k address and want to count how many intersect with each other you need calculate 2.5 billions intersects, so of course will be slow.

What you can do is create a calculate field with the initial data, will be slow but is only one time calculation Then as you said the calculation for a single address is fast you can use a trigger for insert and delete.

So when a new address arrive you intersect with all the 500k other address and add `+1` to the `NoOfAddressesInsideMyPolygon` if the location is inside the polygon

And for delete do the opposite, first check where intersect and subtract `-1`

Now update is trickier. Because you need to check first if the old version contain/inside another address and check the result for the new one to decide if you `{+1, 0, -1}` the counter.